# Excel - Lookup values in table and fill blank cells based on previous data

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the following table, where each ID in the first column has a corresponding fruit in the second, for the most part anyways.

```html
<pre><strong>ID      Fruit</strong><hr>
142     Apple<br>
223     Banana<br>
342     Lemon<br>
223<br>
142     Apple<br>
342<br>
142<br>
462     Apple<br>
```

I want the blank cells in the Fruit column to be filled in automatically based on the ID in the first column. To add a twist, each ID can have only ONE fruit attached, but a fruit can have multiple IDs (e.g. Apple can have IDs 142 AND 462, but 142 can only have APPLE as a value).

At first it seemed a pretty simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried IF, VLOOKUP, and INDEX&MATCH, but none of the codes worked, so I don't have anything to paste in to show where I am at, since I've gotten nowhere until now.

In the meantime I'm also exploring a solution using VBA, although I'm not that familiar with it, so that might take a while.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that the second column is partially filled, and you automatically want to fill the blank cells, without changing the cells which were filled already?

Comment: A simple vlookup should do this unless I am missing something. Just ensure your lookup table lists ids separately and repeats values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C2` this formula should work, and drag it down:

`{=INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(1,(A2=$A$2:$A$9)*($B$2:$B$9<>0),0))}`

**Note:** It's an array function!

And just for the sake of things another option using `=AGGREGATE()`:

`=IF(B2=0,INDEX($B$1:$B$9,AGGREGATE(15,3,((($A$1:$A$9=A2)/($A$1:$A$9=A2))*(($B$1:$B$9<>0)/($B$1:$B$9<>0)))*ROW($A$1:$A$9),1)),B2)`

**Note:** It's wrapped into an `=IF()` to prevent the calculation to happen unwanted

There are even more ways…. :)

Comment: It can even be much simpler, if your statement 'based on previous data' is really what you meant, a simple vlookup should do than, like @Qharr states. Ohwell, formulas can be fun :)

Comment: + for the above though!